# Running Spyder '5' on Debian 11

Tags: python, debian, spyder

Why does calling spyder as 'root' on cli execute the spyder '5' version software, while doing the same as a normal 'user' executes spyder '4'?

How do I make it always  calls in the version '5' from a normal 'user' access level?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `which spyder` when logged in as root and when logged in as normal user.

```
$ which spyder
/usr/bin/which: no spyder in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin)
```

What shell are you using?
Run `echo $SHELL` to see.
You are probably using bash.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

bash and other shells find commands(executables) usually by looking through the PATH environment variable. Run `echo $PATH` to see what your PATH is set to as root and as normal user.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Compare the PATH that is set for root user and other user.

Hopefully this answers the first question.

(p.s. please post a comment or edit question and include the PATH you see for root and other user as well as output of `which spyder` on both)

For the second question:

You can add another dir at the start of PATH on command-line, e.g.

```
$ export PATH=/path/to/other/spyder:$PATH
```

Adding a path in front of the PATH variable will make bash search there first for a matching command name.

You can add a line like that to your .bash_profile or .profile in your $HOME directory OR to more system-wide /etc/profile or other files.

You could also have an environment setup script that you use when switching between different projects or tasks. e.g. script like ~/bin/setup_env_project1.sh    This would be safer than changing PATH for root especially which could have un-intended bad consequences.

For some fun and a short lesson in the dangers of changing your path try this:

```
$ export PATH=
```

Now try some usual commands. Like `ls`, `which ls`, `cd`. Commands like cd and which which are "built into" the bash shell will work ok. However commands like `ls` and `find` and `grep` and `spyder` now cannot be found. Just logout and log back in again to get your $PATH back.

It is a simple thing to add something at start or at end of your $PATH. It's one of the fundamental things in the shell. There is more info all over stackoverflow and the internet in general e.g.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash